# How to append the proper attribute to a series of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation, dom-traversal

I have this bit of code:

```
if ($('.page-template-default .gallery img').attr('alt') !== undefined) {
   $('.page-template-default .gallery li').append("<small>" + $('.page .gallery img').attr('alt') + "</small>");
}
```

Basically it appends the alt text of an image next to the image itself.

Problem is, I have a page with 10 images and the appended alt text is always the same, taken from the first image.

Is there way to return each alt text to the respective image?

Comment: What's the relationship between the images and the `li`s? Can we see your markup?

Comment: `li` are containers. The final HTML should be like this: `<li><a href=""><img alt="" /></a><small>caption</small></li>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be the easiest way:

```
$('.page-template-default .gallery img').attr('alt', function (i, alt) {
    if (typeof alt != 'undefined' && alt!='') {
        $(this).closest('li').append(alt);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gAHhP/)

For a little explanation:

1. [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) can be used with a function as its second parameter. Normally it is used to set the attribute (this time `alt`) using the return value of the function. In this one, I don't return anything, just use it to loop through the `alt` attributes of the specified images.
2. `this` here will refer to the `img` that is currently used
3. [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will return the closest parent of the image that matches the selector `'li'`.

Comment: a slight tweak, since he wants it wrapped in a `<small>`: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gAHhP/2/

Comment: @Nick Thanks, I forgot about that part. Btw, I have learned something new from your fiddle :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each `img` if you want to use properties of each one like this.

```
var $imgs = $('.page-template-default .gallery li > a > img');
$imgs.each(function() {
   var $img = $(this);
   if ($img.attr('alt') !== undefined) {
      var $li = $img.parent().parent();
      $li.append("<small>" + $img.attr('alt') + "</small>");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.page-template-default .gallery img').each(function(i,it) {

  if ($(this).attr('alt') !== undefined) {

     var li = $('.page-template-default .gallery li').get(i);
     $( li ).append("<small>" + $(this).attr('alt') + "</small>");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $imgs = $('.page-template-default .gallery img');
$imgs.each(function($img) {
   if ($img.attr('alt') !== undefined) {
      $img.after("<small>" + $img.attr('alt') + "</small>");
   }
});
```